# asp.net-webhooks and B2C

Tags: asp.net-webhooks

Have you tried asp.net webhooks with ADB2C? (which is brilliant btw) Registration works just fine (App Svc Auth) but the webjob sample will never send a webhook. It seems to depend on a claim that is not available in B2C on registration. There is no ClaimsType.Name ;-( I can see my oid (also the nameidentifier) when I look at the partition key on the registration table storage. I can't find any documentation on the predicate usage in NotifyAllAsync. Anyway- 
user != "Henrik" 
does not fire any webhooks to anyone. 
So sad as it looks cool!

Answer (score 0):

When run use NotifyAsyncAll, you will get called for all *matching* webhooks registrations. That is, the event you send out has to match one or more of the filters that the WebHooks were registered with. If you register a WebHook with a '*' wildcard filter, it will match any event in which case you should see it with NotifyAsyncAll.